# OpenDialog from Firefox add-on with external content can't access window arguments or go back in history

Tags: javascript, firefox, modal-dialog, firefox-addon

I have a small add-on that opens a dialog window with external content.
I have not found a way to pass data to the child window to let it know it is a dialog window.
I need to do this so that javascript code loaded into the dialog window knows it has to close.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

The history.back() does not work for documents loaded into said window either but I don' know why.

```
var MACDialogExtension = {
 myListener: function(evt) {
 console.log(evt.target.ownerDocument);

 window.openDialog(evt.target.getAttribute("url"),evt.target.getAttribute("name"),evt.target.getAttribute("features"),"child");
  }     
}
document.addEventListener("MACDialogExtensionEvent", function(e) { MACDialogExtension.myListener(e); }, false, true);
```

I thought the document loaded into the dialog would get access to the window argumens, but it doesn't. 
Can you think other way to pass parameters into the window? I just need the document inside that window that they are inside a dialog window.

Comment: For me, it's not that `window.arguments` doesn't work, but it's that it only works with primitives! I can pass numbers, booleans and strings, but if I pass an object, the dialog gets an empty object with all the fields stripped! I even tried this [wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/wrappedJSObject) trick but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox dialogs have a Dialog global object that might work for you although I'm not sure if it would work from an external content window:

```
Dialog.args
```

So you're saying window.arguments[0] doesn't work?

What if you load a different (e.g. simpler) external document?

I think you'll need to provide some more code if none of this helps.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: Dialog is not defined`. For me, it's not that `window.arguments` doesn't work, but it's that it only works with primitives! I can pass numbers, booleans and strings, but if I pass an object, the dialog gets an empty object with all the fields stripped! I even tried this [wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/wrappedJSObject) trick but in vain. This API is really brittle. Even the examples from MDN didn't work for me.